Creating Macros Adds a Space to Text At the End?
Here are 2 simple examples yielding strange results to me:
\newcommand\textCmr[1]{
  {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont \footnotesize{#1}}
}

\newcommand\shref[2]{
  \small{\href{#1}{\path{#2}}}
}

If I, for example, use \small{\href{#1}{\path{#2}}} inline, then I think things work as expected, but, if I use it from a macro, then TeX seems to add a small space at the end?

How do I make the macro behave like inline text?

Off-topic: \footnotesize and \small are switches and don't take brace-delimited arguments. Hence, you should replace \footnotesize{#1} with {\footnotesize #1}, and also replace \small{\href{#1}{\path{#2}}} with {\small\href{#1}{\path{#2}}} in order to properly delimit the scope of \footnotesize and \small.

well you have spaces in your macro, end of lines are spaces.

Damn. That's so simple. Thanks! I forgot I should be using % at the end of the lines in such cases!

As @UlrikeFischer has pointed out in a comment, TeX converts the (usually invisible) end-of-line characters to whitespace. And, keep in mind that \footnotesize and \small are switches, i.e., their scope is the end of the current TeX group. And, as @egreg has noted in a further comment, it's not necessary to issue an explicit \selectfont directive since the \fontfamily directive is followed by a font size-changing command (here: \footnotesize).  Hence, do please change
\newcommand\textCmr[1]{
  {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\footnotesize{#1}}
}
\newcommand\shref[2]{
  \small{\href{#1}{\path{#2}}}
}

to
\newcommand\textCmr[1]{%
  {\fontfamily{cmr}\footnotesize #1}%
}
\newcommand\shref[2]{%
  {\small\href{#1}{\path{#2}}}%
}


By the way, {\fontfamily{cmr}\footnotesize #1} is simpler. Any font size changing command, like \bfseries, \itshape and so on, issues \selectfont.

@egreg - Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer accordingly.

The comment is misleading: it is generally necessary to issue \selectfont after \fontfamily{foo}, but in this case it isn't because of the following \footnotesize.

@egreg - Thanks for this. I've corrected my answer.
